# I want my zeros to be some other number/character (C++)

Tags: c++, c++17, double, precision

```
double floaty=36.6736872;
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(10)<<floaty;
```

My output is "**36.6736872000**";

I want my zeros to be some other number.
Eg: If I want zeros to be `^`.

then the output should be   **36.6736872^^^**

I don't have any idea other than using `setw` and `setfill` to get my desired output in single line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [std::ostringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream), and change the resulting string in any way you see fit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double floaty=36.6736872;
    std::ostringstream strm;

    // Get the output as a string  
    strm << std::fixed << std::setprecision(10) << floaty;
    std::string out = strm.str();

    // Process the output
    auto iter = out.rbegin();
    while (iter != out.rend() && *iter == '0')
    {
       *iter = '^';
       ++iter;
    }
    std::cout << out;
}
```

Output:

```
36.6736872^^^
```